# Low disk space TFS backup

Tags: tfs, backup, disaster-recovery

I would like to know what happens when the disk space on which the shared folder resides on which full and incremental TFS backups are saved. In my configuration, the disk where backups are made is not the disk where there is the TFS database. If there is insufficient disk space for continuous backups to work with TFS for various clients?

Answer (score 0):

The backups will fail and you will not be able to restore your TFS server in case of a corruption.

Answer (score 0):

TFS automatic Backup is fundamental to restore your work in case of problem.

So I suggest You to use it.

If needed not to use a lot of disk space you can reduce retention days for old backups from TFS administration console in backup tab, basically similar for last TFS versions. Take care to have at least one full backup saved.

See [Backing up and Restoring your TFS Server for TFS 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2010/08/18/backing-up-and-restoring-your-tfs-server/)